# Ignore alphabetical strings while sorting an array of rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array consisting of table rows based on a particular value of a column. This column may sometimes contain any text like `N/A` or `Not available` or any alphabet and also contains `strings` of numbers like `23` or `25.26`. While sorting I need to put the rows that contain `text strings` at the bottom while both ascending and descending sorting. So basically I must ignore those rows that contain those text values but move those rows at the end. My present code is like this:

```
studentResults.sort(function(a, b){
      if(a.querySelector(".percentage_value") == undefined) return 1;
      if(b.querySelector(".percentage_value") == undefined) return 0;
      var percentageValueText1 = a.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent;
      var percentageValueText2 = b.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent;
      return sortDirection == -1 ? (percentageValueText1 > percentageValueText2) : (percentageValueText1 < percentageValueText2);
    })
```

So I need to add the functionality of ignoring alphabetical strings here. Add sort the rows and place at the top in ascending or descending orders.

Comment: I suggest that you create an array with objects or maybe Maps, where you have converted the values ONE time instead of MULTIPLE times (each time the sort function is called).Then your sort function is simpler and a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 4 cases:

- a and b are both non-numbers - your compare function should return 0
- a is not a number - return 1 to sort b ahead of a
- b is not a number - return -1 to sort a ahead of b
- a and b are both numbers - do a standard cmp between numbers, depending on your sort direction

Here's a full example, with the relevant code being the `rowCmp` function:

```js
var sortDirection = -1;

var sortRows = function() {
    var table = document. querySelector('table');
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    rows.forEach(function(row) {row.parentNode.removeChild(row);});
    
    var rowArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0);
    rowArray.sort(rowCmp);
    rowArray.forEach(function(row) {table.appendChild(row);});
    
}

var rowCmp = function(a, b) {
    var val_a = a.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent;
    var val_b = b.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent;

    if (isNaN(val_a) && isNaN(val_b)) return 0;
    if (isNaN(val_a)) return 1;
    if (isNaN(val_b)) return -1;

    // we know that a and b are both numbers if we have not returned before here

    var num_a = parseFloat(val_a);
    var num_b = parseFloat(val_b);
    // assuming sortDirection is either 1 or -1
    return Math.sign(num_a - num_b) * sortDirection;
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td class="percentage_value">0.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fred Jones</td>
    <td class="percentage_value">N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>W. Ed Edison</td>
    <td class="percentage_value">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Z. McKraken</td>
    <td class="percentage_value">Not available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Norman Bates</td>
    <td class="percentage_value">0.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="sortRows()">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code also sorts the text strings. It does not ignore the text strings.

Comment: @Laxman are there any errors in your javascript console? I'd mistyped `isNaN` as `isNan` in a number of places which might have been the cause of that bug. I've updated my answer, please can you try again?

Comment: No. I changed that spelling and then executed the code.

Comment: @Laxman I've changed this to include an executable example now to show that this approach works. How does your setup differ to this?

Comment: This is a part of the bigger code. I have pasted the whole code on codereview. Can I paste the link to that question here? Or should I change this question itself?

Comment: This is the link where I have pasted the whole code. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220806/vanilla-javascript-code-to-sort-nested-tables